# Casting to Time in SQL fails after 1762 rows

Tags: sql, casting, sql-server-2012

(Updated followings comments)

I got a strange behaviour on SQL server 2012, this request is ok :

```
select top 2002 cast(myTimeStr as time) from tbWithTime
order by ID
```

but

```
select top 2003 cast(myTimeStr as time) from tbWithTime
order by ID
```

failed with

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Whereas line 2002 and 2003 both equals to '14:30'

Then when i try to specifically cast this 2003 line, it succeeded.

My configuration :

```
Name                                                    Version
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                  10.50.1600.1
Microsft SQL Server 2012                                11.0.3339.0
```

Comment: Without `ORDER BY` there is no guarantee of what row 1,763 even is.

Comment: Without an `ORDER BY` clause, there's no way to reliably know which row is being processed 1763rd, versus any other way of accessing the data and trying to determine which row that is.

Comment: In fact, when i get the distinct value of my table, the conversion works for all so i don't think there is an ugly duckling.

Comment: could you try your 2 queries and add order by newid()

Comment: @t-clausen.dk In this case , both of them fails

Comment: So, now you know it's not some witchcraft about number 1763 but there is a row (or rows) out there that fails to cast - and is just the matter to find them now. Use any reasonable `ORDER BY` and try to pinpoint it.

Comment: Also, there shouldn't be difference between CAST and CONVERT but give a try with `CONVERT` and `TRY_CAST`

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic Question updated

Comment: Convert fails the same way

Comment: Can you show us the two rows where it fails? But please copy/paste the values from SSMS results, do not rewrite them. Perhaps there is a some strange character that fails the conversion (and passes TRY_CONVERT), that is not visible.

Comment: Also, please tell what is datatype (and lenght) of `myTimeStr` column

Comment: First of all , i know it s weird but line changed since this morning. It's now 2995-2996. Second, here are the values 
    13:30
    13:30
Finally , type is VARCHAR(50)

Answer (score 2):

To find the actual row(s) causing you issues, try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tbWithTime WHERE TRY_CONVERT(time,myTimeStr) IS NULL
```

[`TRY_CONVERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx):

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds; otherwise, returns null.

Comment: I tried this function before but due to system issue, it doesn't work : Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'TRY_CONVERT' is not a recognized built-in function name.
I know what i have to do to make it right but i don't have the rights to do it and i won't have it

Comment: @FabricePA In that case you are not using SQL Server 2012. Run `@@Version` to find out correct version... EDIT: OR your Database is set to older compatibility level and does not support 2012 commands.

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic : Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3339.0 (X64)   Jan 14 2013 19:02:10   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: I should do that http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting110.htm but i can't due to installation problem (MSSQLMS 2012 doesn't work on XP..)

Comment: @FabricePA - You can use `ALTER` command to change compatibility http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx

Comment: @FabricePA - [`ALTER DATABASE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx) should work, even if you're running a query from an older management studio.

Comment: @FabricePA - If you can't change compatibility for some reason can you try `USE master;SELECT * FROM YourDb..tbWithTime WHERE TRY_CONVERT(time,myTimeStr) IS NULL`?

Comment: @Nenad Zivkovic That worked! Great! Thanks! Nevertheless, 
Damien_The_Unbeliever 's command returned me nothing. And i still have this strange error message

Answer (score 1):

You could try this to find the funny rows:

```
select myTimeStr
from tbWithTime
where  myTimeStr not like '[0-1][0-9][:][0-5][0-9]'
   and myTimeStr not like '2[0-3][:][0-5][0-9]'
```

Or you could just select the valid rows:

```
select cast(myTimeStr as time) 
from tbWithTime
where myTimeStr like '[0-1][0-9][:][0-5][0-9]'
   or myTimeStr like '2[0-3][:][0-5][0-9]'
```

Comment: As my final comment of  Damien_The_Unbeliever answer, it doesn't return any result.

Comment: @FabricePA if both queries returns 0 results, there is something really odd

Comment: not both of them, just the first one. I already resolved my initial problem with another way so i have no use of the second which actually works.